# CodeIgniter 4: $this->post call failing

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am working through Lonnie Ezell's book on CodeIgniter 4, and am busy with project 4, dealing with unit testing. The code samples are here:

- https://github.com/lonnieezell/ci4-foundations/blob/master/project-04-part-ii/app/Controllers/PostController.php
- https://github.com/lonnieezell/ci4-foundations/blob/master/project-04-part-ii/tests/PostCrudTest.php

I have implemented my code exactly like this (copied and pasted code) and in particular the functions `testCanEditPost()` in the Test, which is the only test that is failing, and `save` in `PostController`.

First of all, the `if (! $this->validate...` call always fails - this is the primary issue - I have outputted the validation errors, and it keeps saying that "The x field is required", even though the data is available. If I move the `$post = ($postID === null ? ...` code to the top, I can see my `title`, `body` and `publish_at`, which are retrieved from `new Post($this->request->getPost()`. I know this because further down, the $postId always remains null, for some reason (see below), but doing this does show the fields (title, body and publish_it) but postId is empty:

```
$post = ($postId === null ? new Post($this->request->getPost()) : $this->posts->find($postId));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($postId);
print_r($post);
echo '</pre>';
exit(); // I am removing this debug text after testing, so the exit() here is not why it does not complete correctly.
```

Secondly, the empty `$postId`. So - calling this:

```
$response = $this->post("posts/{$post->id}", [
    'title' => 'Post A',
    'publish_at' => date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('+1 week')),
    'body' => 'My Great Post'
]);
```

Does not pass the `$post->id` through to the `PostController` `save` function's `$postId` parameter. `$post->id` is populated, so I am not passing a null through to the `save` function. My route is also copied from the example:

```
$routes->post('posts/(:num)', 'PostController::save/$1');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, what does "*even though the data is available*" mean?  And why have you written "*The **x** field*" rather than any specific one of your fields?  Have you tried dumping the request to check what is in it?  I haven't used CI4 but it looks like `print_r($this->request->getVar());` in your controller should do it.  Have you checked devtools to inspect the request from the browser? Side note - I don't think this is a problem but you have an extra set of unnecessary brackets around your `$post = ($postId === null ...` ternary which just makes it harder to read and easier to mess up.

Comment: The 'x' field, means that instead of writing it out 3 times, it does that for each field in the validation. So, 'The title field is required', 'The body field is required' etc. With data being available, as stated, if I echo out the post data, id, title, body and publish_at is set.